# Finding the largest possible order of an element in $\mathbb Z_{6} \times \mathbb Z_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find an element of $\mathbb Z_{6}\times\mathbb Z_{10}$ having the largest possible order.

The largest possible order is lcm$(6,10) = 30$, correct? So how would I go about finding an element with this order? Not sure how to continue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reall that for the direct product $G \times H$ of groups we have for $g\in G$, $h \in H$ that $\def\ord{\mathop{\rm ord}}$
$$ \ord (g,h) = \mathrm{lcm}(\ord g, \ord h) $$
hence taking an element of order $6$ from $\mathbb Z_6$, say $1 + 6\mathbb Z$ and an element of order $10$ from $\mathbb Z_{10}$, say $1 + 10\mathbb Z$ gives an element 
$$ (1 + 6 \mathbb Z, 1 + 10 \mathbb Z) \in \mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z_{10} $$ 
of order 30.

Comment: Ah so simply (1, 1) would have order 30?

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Comment: It's easy to check the order of $(1,1)$ is not $1,2,3,4,5,6$ or $15$: we see that $(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)$ are not the identity, nor is $6(1,1) = (0,6)$, or $15(1,1) = (3,5)$.