# Finding the maximum order of an element in a product group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to find the maximum order of an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times \mathbb{Z}_{8}$. I found a previous similar thread ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175157/finding-the-largest-possible-order-of-an-element-in-mathbb-z-6-times-mathb?rq=1)). But I can't seem to understand how they calculated the order.

I know that $o((g,h))=lcm(o(g),o(h))$ but how does it help to calculate the maximum order? From the thread I learn to calculate:

$$ (1 + 4 \mathbb Z, 1 + 8 \mathbb Z) \in \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_{8} $$

But what does it gives to me?

Answer (score 2):

The order of an element in the product is the lcm of its two components. But you know the possible orders of the elements of $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_8$ because they are cylic. Namely, $1$, $2$ and $4$ are the possible orders in $\mathbb Z_4$, and $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$ are the possible orders in $\mathbb Z_8$.

It remains to see that the maximum lcm we can get from the possible pairs is $8$, which is the order of any pair $(x,1)$ for $x\in \mathbb Z_4$.

Comment: so the answer is $8$?

Comment: You should convince yourself that it is the answer.